# Deploying JRuby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat, jetty, jruby

First time I am working on a JRuby on Rails application. I was wondering what is the de facto deployment stack for JRuby on Rails app. So far I see the following:

1. Jetty
2. Tomcat

Please share why you would think in favor of one over the other. Thank you for your time.

Comment: With JRuby and Warbler, you can deploy to any servlet or application server.  In addition to these, you have Glassfish, JBoss and Torquebox (which is built on top of JBoss).  If you're familiar with the Java ecosystem, use what you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no a de facto deploymanet stack, you can choose what you prefer or what you think is better.
I personally use warbler to package my rails app as war and deploy it on JBoss.

If you need something more integrated there is Torquebox http://torquebox.org, which let you use messaging, clustering, etc... Give it a try because it's really powerfull!

Answer (score 0):

The question really is which container has better support in your infrastructure or by your service provider.

In my company JBoss 5.2 is the only way to deploy any web apps. That's why we chose JRuby over MRI in the first place.